# How to add the parameter name in custom validation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to ask about custom validation. I make validation for counting the word

```
Validator::extend('word_count', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

       return str_word_count($value) >= $parameters;

});
```

How can i give name to parameter so that i can use the parameter value in error message?

Comment: What you want exactly please specify. You want the error message with value entered by user. right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, i will understand you care about the validation message.

If you are looking for validation message mean, you can use custom message like,

If you are using the **request** file means, there we can use

```
messages(){
   return [
    'word_count' => '....', //some message will be here,
   ];
}
```

If you are using **controller** means, then use like

```
return response()->json('...', 422);
```

or

here also you can use that above **messages** function.

I hope, it will help you.If any thing ask here.